# how to replace value in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm opening a `<iframe>` and copying some of its content to another iframe.

The HTML I am copying is here:

```html
<input type="text" name="LABEL" value="TEST MARKASHEADER">
```

I want to remove the portion of the value `"MARKASHEADER"` and then leave whatever text is left.

I have tried this code below and can't get anything to work to remove `"MARKASHEADER"`.

```js
$("#iframe").contents().find("input[name='LABEL']").val($("#iframe").contents().find("input[name='LABEL']").val().replace("MARKASHEADER",''));
```

Comment: Is the iframe and the host (parent) page on the same domain?

Comment: yes they are both same domain

Comment: I think that perhaps browsers have changed since jquery's iframe.contents() method was created. Tests I have been doing shows this will not work at least in current version of chrome. If I were you I would look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage as a work around. This will allows you to communicate between an iframe and the page that it is embedded in. Communicate some string that tells your inner page to execute the command you want.